# Function getting called twice on keypress of SPACEBAR in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm calling a function on click of button and its working fine. But when I'm focusing over button and pressing spacebar from keyboard then function is getting called twice on firefox browser while its working properly on chrome. On pressing enter key also working fine. The issue is only with spacebar.

```js
function myFunction(name, eventNode) {
  console.log("here");
  // callingAnotherFunction(name);             
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-transparent dropdown-toggle" onClick="myFunction('test', this)"><i class="ico ico-cm-arrow"></i>Click me</button>
```

Printing "here" twice on console on spacebar press

Comment: Most likely due to a quirk in Firefox where the space keypress is also raising a click, as well as the click itself triggered from keyboard interaction with a button.

Comment: Yes firefox has the issue but its an AVT issue so I need some workaround here.

Comment: Also note that the above snippet does not recreate the behaviour in FF62

Comment: I'm using FF63 latest one

Comment: I just upgraded, still doesn't happen in FF63 in Win10

Comment: Going to confirm that I also don't get the issue on FF62 + FF63 on Windows 10.

Comment: Well but its still not working for me.

Comment: As a work around, you could implement a debounce version of the function to prevent it from firing twice within a certain time constraint. View the lodash implementation: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce

Comment: I just used a ```keyup``` listener and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround you can use that would separate the space from the click. The space as a click event is buggy in many browsers, so you can call an onmousedown or onmouseup event and also call an onkeyup event and check if it's a spacebar.

```js
function myFunction(name, eventNode) {
  console.log("here");
  // callingAnotherFunction(name);             
}

function keypress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == "32") {
    myFunction('test', this);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-transparent dropdown-toggle" onmouseup="myFunction('test', this)" onkeyup="keypress(event)"><i class="ico ico-cm-arrow"></i>Click me</button>
```